# Disable "Back" in Chrome's context menu

Tags: google-chrome, context-menu

I'm using chrome and like to right click links, then select 'Open in new tab'. If I slightly mis-click, the regular context menu opens instead, and as its top item is 'Back', such occurs, much to my annoyance.

If 'Back' and 'Forward' were switched, so the top item were 'Forward' (thus most of the time disabled), this would not be a problem. I'd also be happy to remove 'Back' altogether.

Ctrl+click is not a solution as it requires two hands, which I do not always want to spare (e.g. when busy facepalming). Middle click is a solution, but a bit cumbersome, and I would prefer to instead customize the browser.

Comment: @Brandito maybe [one of these plugins can help](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/context-menu-editor/inlamfmomfahaglpmifhlfmomgmdicin/related) ?

Comment: @1NN: Nothing can touch these first items in the menu.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: let's go with Windows 10

Comment: Actually my answer finally pertains to all OS.

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome context-menu cannot be edited to remove items, even by an extension.
This is the way that the API is defined at
[chrome.contextMenus](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/#method-remove).
An extension may only remove additional entries that it created, so no extension
can remove the built-in entries.

The only solution would be to block the Back action itself.

**Method 1 : Tampermonkey extension - JavaScript injection**

One way of disabling the Back function is by by injecting JavaScript code into all
web pages, by using the
[Tampermonkey extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).

The JavaScript code to inject is
([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59388091/165358)):

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
    history.back();
    history.forward();
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        history.go(1);
    };
</script>
```

For information on using Tampermonkey, see for example:
[How to Inject Scripts to Websites Using TamperMonkey](https://medium.com/@ridbay/how-to-inject-scripts-to-websites-using-tampermonkey-cffca17c8e2e).

**Method 2 : No History extension**

Another helpful extension is the
[No History extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-history/ljamgkbcojbnmcaonjokopmcblmmpfch?hl=en).

This extension disables history and therefore also the possibility of doing Back.
Even the Back button is disabled.

The extension can be toggled On and Off, and its drawback is that
you will not have any history while it is On.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot customize the context menu within Chrome. It is not made by Chrome, but instead your own computer's program. Maybe you could change it in your settings.

Comment: Your answer is confusing and technically incorrect. Chrome _is_ your computer's program. Everything that runs on your computer is a program. There's no "own" computer's program. You could be talking about the operating system, but then it's not true that the context menu cannot be customized, because it can. The only reason why Chrome's context menu is not customizable is because Chrome developers didn't want it to be.